# Can an RF module be used for ZigBee?

Tags: rf, radio, zigbee, transceiver

I am very new to wireless communication protocols so please excuse me if this is a silly question. 
I am using a PIC to communicate between two Zigbee modules. However I also own a 2.4GHz RF transceiver module. Would it be possible to use the RF transceiver module to read the data coming from the Zigbee module?

The Zigbee module is the MRF24J40MA
The RF transceiver is the nRF24L01P RF transceiver chip with 2.4 GHz chip antenna.

Answer (score 1):

Different kind of wireless modules, use specific modulation techniques. Some kind of modulations are FSK, PSK, GPSK, , QPSK, OQPSK and so many other techniques.

Different modulation means different technique to decoding received signal. It's so vital that receiver and transmitter use exactly same modulation and coding.

For this reason you've to always use same type receiver and transmitter for communicating. you cant handle a Zigbee module by a RF module or a Bluetooth one. You also can't use two different type of RF module for communicating in most cases. Then for more reliable and secure connection Always use same type of modules for receiver and transmitter.

Answer (score 0):

Zigbee is a protocol that rides on top of the IEEE 802.15.4 mac/phy layers. You need a radio that can demodulate IEEE 802.15.4 signals to sniff and decode raw Zigbee packets, and your Nordic radio uses a proprietary protocol (not IEEE 802.15.4) so unfortunately it won't work.